# read string and put contents to struct

Tags: c#, string, struct

I receive a string on PC, that's basically a sequence of byte-per-byte several shorts. I need to put that string into struct. For example, I need to put `Hello!` into this struct:

```
public struct serialPacket
{
    public ushort first;
    public ushort second;
    public ushort third;
}
```

to get it like this:

```
temp.first=0x6548;
temp.second=0x6c6c;
temp.third=0x216f;
```

I'm not very sure about endianness, but that doesn't matter right now.
I am really frustrated, because in C/C++ it could be easily done with a little help of pointers, but I don;t know how to fix it in C#.
I'm using `Marshal` to handle this, but I get some junk in result:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct serialPacket
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort first;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort second;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort third;
}
...
IntPtr pBuf = Marshal.StringToBSTR(indata);
serialPacket ms = (serialPacket)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pBuf, typeof(serialPacket));
Marshal.FreeBSTR(pBuf);
```

result:
1st 101
2nd 72
3rd 108
Looks more like marshalling tears ushorts apart by single byte. The string itself is received complete, in one single shot. And it is received with a 0x0D at the end as a NewLine

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
temp.first = 0x6548;
temp.second = 0x6c6c;
temp.third = 0x216f;

Func<ushort, string> conv = u =>
{
    var bs = BitConverter.GetBytes(u);
    return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bs);
};

var query =
    from u in new [] { temp.first, temp.second, temp.third, }
    select conv(u);

var result = String.Join("", query);
// result == "Hello!"
```